# How to mock a method having lambda expression

Tags: java, powermock

```
        ClientBuilder builder = ResteasyClientBuilder.newBuilder();
        builder = builder.sslContext(sslContext);
        builder = builder.hostnameVerifier((s1,s2)-> true);
```

I want to mock the builder.hostnameVerifier

I tried it in different way,

for first 2 lines I am able to mock. my code as below:

```
    PowerMockito.mockStatic(ResteasyClientBuilder.class);
    PowerMockito.when(ResteasyClientBuilder.newBuilder()).thenReturn(clientBuilder);
    PowerMockito.when(clientBuilder.sslContext(sslContext)).thenReturn(clientBuilder);
    PowerMockito.when(this.verifier.verify(Matchers.anyString(), Matchers.anyObject())).thenReturn(true);
    PowerMockito.when(clientBuilder.hostnameVerifier(this.verifier)).thenReturn(clientBuilder);
```

Comment: So what is your issue exactly?

Comment: When I dubug over here, I am getting null object on third line. It is lambda expression and I have mocked it differently.

Comment: you could use Matchers.any(HostnameVerifier.class), can't you?

Comment: Oh, of course. Well I don't think you can mock this properly with a fixed expression (ie in your case `this.verifier`), because that won't match the lambda that is actually passed. I think you can only do `when(cb.hostnameVerifier(any())).thenReturn(...)`.